# Computing a specific direct limit

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology

Suppose we have the following sequence of $\mathbb{Z}$-modules
$$G\,\,\overset{M}{\longrightarrow}\,\, G\,\,\overset{M}{\longrightarrow}\,\, G\,\,\overset{M}{\longrightarrow}\,\, \cdots,$$

where each $G:=(\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{2\mathbb{Z}})^5\oplus\mathbb{Z}^5$,  and the bonding map $M$ is given by the square matrix \begin{eqnarray*}
M:=\left(
\begin{array}{cccccccccc}
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right).
\end{eqnarray*} For example, if $t=(t_1,\ldots,t_{10})\in \mathbb{Z}^{10}$,  then the element $([t_1]_2,\ldots,[t_5]_2,t_6,\ldots,t_{10})\in G$ is mapped to $([(Mt)_1]_2,\ldots,[(Mt)_5]_2,(Mt)_6,\ldots,(Mt)_{10})$. What is the direct limit of such sequence?

Comment: Can you say anything interesting bout the lower right quarter submatrix of $M$?

Comment: Where does this problem come from? It looks a little arbitrary... Anyway, the matrix in the lower right corner is diagonalizable with eigenvalues $6,1,1,1,1$., where the eigenspace of $6$ is spanned by $[1,0,1,1,1]$. And in general, if you denote the matrices in the upper right and lower right corner with $A$ and $B$, then $M^n$ has the same form with $AB^{n-1}$ and $B^n$ instead of $A$ and $B$, respectively. That should help, I guess.

Comment: For each $i\in\mathbb{N}$ we let $G_i=G$ and view $M$ as a map from $G_i$ to $G_{i+1}$.  Then the direct limit is $\oplus G_i/\sim$ where the equivalence relation $\sim$ is generated by declaring that $x\sim Mx$ for $x\in G_i$ for any $i$ (Note that here $Mx\in G_{i+1}$.  Let $K_i=\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}^5\subseteq G_i$.  Then $M$ annihilates $K_i$ so for $x\in K_i$, $x\sim Mx = 0$.  Hence the image of $K_i$ in the limit is 0.  Essentially this should mean that we can ignore the summand $\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}^5$ and just take the limit of $\mathbb{Z}^5$.

Comment: If the lower right corner of your matrix is diagonalizable as Lukas suggests, then it is not difficult to see that your direct limit is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z[1/6]\oplus \mathbb Z^4$. 
Use the fact that the direct limit of a system of the form
$\mathbb Z\overset{n}{\to}\mathbb Z\overset{n}{\to}\dots \overset{n}{\to}\mathbb Z\overset{n}{\to}\dots$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z[1/n]$, where $\mathbb Z[1/n]$ is the subring of $\mathbb Q$ generated by $1/n$.